# WCF service is not working. What is the issue here?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have below method in WCFHOST and its a console.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080");

            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1),baseAddress))
            {
                // Enable metadata publishing.
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since
                // no endpoints are explicitly configured, the runtime will create
                // one endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented
                // by the service.
                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
                Console.ReadLine();

                // Close the ServiceHost.
                host.Close();
            }
        }
```

Below is my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="Service1" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService.IService1"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <!--<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfService/Service1/"/>-->
           <!--<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>-->
            <!--<add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090/"/>-->
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

After run the app when I put below URL on the browser. Nothing happening

```
http://localhost:8080/Service1.svc/GetWithInPremesisMembers?dateFrom=2021-04-08&dateTo=2021-04-08
```

Whats the issue here?
This is working fine in IIS (When this hosted on server). I just want to debug the code from VS 2013.

Comment: SOAP uses POST, not GET. Have you actually tried to create a client? Did you try any of the WCF tutorials?

Comment: Yep I created a client. This is working fine in IIS. I just want to debug the code from VS 2013.

Comment: SOAP uses POST and the entire request is part of the XML body. Use the client you created, the [WcfTestClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-test-client-wcftestclient-exe) tool or SOAP UI. If you want to write a unit/integration test, add a Service Reference to the service

Comment: Try changing the uri in the first image to `"http://localhost:8080/Your Method"`.